# Regex ignore string

Tags: python, regex

Event one and two have the same field types; Event 3 has an additional column appended to the front.  I want to ignore the first column in event 3 and just capture the other 3 fields, using regex.

event one:

```
"gvonsoT6dvnogn" "gn12sdgnwgn" "gnsod5-gnsopdgn"
```

event two:

```
- "voksjnd3aY_vgoksn" -
```

event three:

```
"abcnoandvondvoavnoavnaovd8745n"  "aondvoanvo" - -
```

Here is my regex whicih is not quiet working:

```
^(?![abc]*[\"\s])(?<x1>[^ ]+)\s(?<x2>[^ ]+)\s(?<x3>[^ ]+)
 \______________/
```

Comment: What tool/language do you use? and what is the critera to ignore the column? the fact that it begins with `abc` or when there are more than three columns?

Comment: phython and the criteria for the ignore is it starts with abc

Comment: are non-empty columns always between quotes?

Comment: yes non-empty columns are always between quotes

Comment: Maybe [`(?m)(?P<x1>[^ \n]+)\s+(?P<x2>[^ \n]+)\s+(?P<x3>[^ \n]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/pL8aR7/1) will do? It will capture just the 3 fields at the end of the line.

Comment: @stribizhev  thanks, however, I just tried it and no luck.

Comment: Can column values contain spaces, or is it only used to separate different column values.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your pattern slightly:

```
^(?:"?abc\S*\s+)?(?P<x1>\S+)\s+(?P<x2>\S+)\s+(?P<x3>\S+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB4iC9/1)

The first group will match the unneeded value, but it's not a capture group.

I also replaced `[^ ]` with `\S` and `\s` with `\s+` to make regex101 happy with your provided examples.

Comment: still not quite working, the " is removed but the rest of acb* is still there

Comment: @t_k looks like it's working in regex101 for your provided examples (look at the colors). Can you provide an example where it fails? Maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: regex101 your using the global \g\m.  I cannot use those; however, we are getting closer.  That is for sure.

Comment: @t_k I have to use them in regex101 just so it acts as a demo (otherwise you'd get only the first match). Maybe you should edit your question to include some sample code you're having difficulties with.

Comment: (?:"abc.*?"\s)?(?<x1>[^ ]+)\s(?<x2>[^ ]+)\s(?<x3>[^ ]+)